# How to delete Config.msi

Tags: file-management, windows-11

I'm having trouble deleting folder `E:\Config.msi` on Windows 11, and according to various websites I've read, this file is sometimes leftover after an application installation and is safe to remove.

How can I get rid of `Config.msi`?

- My searches for relevant information turns up only one site that speaks to this folder, but its instructions aren't relevant to Windows 11
- `Config.msi` does not appear in File Explorer even though I've set it to display hidden and system files, with the following executed from `E:\` in an Admin terminal:

  ```bsh
  $ dir /AS*
    Directory of E:\

    12/23/2021  19:12PM   DIR $RECYCLE.BIN
    01/21/2022  22:12PM   DIR Config.Msi
    12/23/2021  20:11PM   DIR System Volume Information

      0 File(s)  0 bytes
      3 Dir(s)   463,314,694,144 bytes free

  $ attrib Config.msi
    SH E:\Config.Msi

  $ del Config.msi
    Could Not Find E:\Config.msi\*

  $ attrib -s
    config.msi Not resetting hidden file - E:\Config.Msi

  $ attrib -h
    config.msi Not resetting system file - E:\Config.Msi

  $ del Config.msi
    Could Not Find E:\Config.msi\*
  ```

Comment: Try `rd /s /q config.msi` `rd` is remove directory, `/s` is delete sub-directories and `/q` is to do it quietly.

Comment: AAAARRRGGGGHHHH!!!  Why did I forget rd?  OF COURSE that worked.  My mushy brain thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong command. You're trying to delete a folder, but `del` is for deleting one or more files.

Instead, you want to use `rd` or `rmdir` (same command, different name).

For example, `rd /s /q config.msi`

The `/s` flag ensures sub-folders are deleted too

The `/q` flag doesn't prompt you to confirm every sub/directory.